# Problems of Implementing Audio Recording Repeatly in A Unity C# Program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, speech-recognition, record

I have the following problem, When I want to start the second recording process, the 'realTime' variable can't be reset to 0 and other debuglog does not execute, which may mean that the methods that are relevant to the 'realTime' variable does not be invoked in the second recording. How can I fix the code?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioRecorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int DeviceLength; //设备长度
    private string NowTime;
    private string[] mDevice;  //设备
    private int Frequency = 44100;//录音频率
    private int MaxSecond = 36;//最长录音时长
    private int realTime = 0;//实际录音时长
    private string filePath;//文件夹路径
    private string currentName;
    private string starttime;//开始时间
    private string endtime;//结束时间
    AudioSource _curAudioSource;//需要绑定在一个AudioSource
    public Action Finished;
    //public static AudioRecorder instance;
    AudioSource CurAudioSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_curAudioSource == null)
            {
                _curAudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            }
            return _curAudioSource;
        }
    }
    private KeywordRecognizer recognizer;
    private string[] keywords = { "Start Recording", "Stop Recording" };
    private bool isRecording = false;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private bool isStopped = false;
    private AudioClip currentClip;
    private AudioClip recordingClip;
    private int recordingLength = 3600; // 1 hour recording length
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //if (instance == null)
        //    instance = this;
        //此处是保存的路径,根据项目需求设定
        filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Audio";
        if (Directory.Exists(filePath) == false)//如果不存在就创建file文件夹
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }
        #region
        /// <summary>
        /// 获取麦克风设备
        /// </summary>
        mDevice = Microphone.devices;
        DeviceLength = mDevice.Length;
        if (DeviceLength == 0)
            ShowInfoLog("找不到麦克风设备！");
        Debug.Log(mDevice[1]);
        Debug.Log(mDevice[1]);
        #endregion  获取麦克风设备

        recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords, ConfidenceLevel.Low);
        recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += OnPhraseRecognized;
        recognizer.Start();
    }
    void OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        string command = args.text;
        ShowInfoLog("DDD");
        if (command == "Start Recording")
        {
            isRecording = true;
            // currentClip = null;
            //  recordingClip = Microphone.Start(null, false, recordingLength, 44100);
            //CurAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(mDevice[1], true, MaxSecond, Frequency);
            //StartRecordAudio();
        }
        if (command == "Stop Recording")
        {
            isRecording = false;
            //StopRecordAudio();
            //PrintRecordData();
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isRecording)
        {
            StartRecordAudio();
        }
        else
        {
            StopRecordAudio();
            // PrintRecordData();
        }
    }
    public void StartRecordAudio()
    {

        ShowInfoLog("Begin Recording........");
        Debug.Log(mDevice[1]);
        if (isStarted)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        CurAudioSource.Stop();
        CurAudioSource.loop = false;
        CurAudioSource.mute = true;
        CurAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(mDevice[1], true, MaxSecond, Frequency);
        // Microphone.Start(mDevice[1], true, MaxSecond, Frequency);
        while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(mDevice[1]) > 0))
        {

        }
        // CurAudioSource.Play();
        starttime = GetCurrentTime();
        realTime = 0;
        //开始计时,最大时间后生成一次录音文件
        if (IsInvoking("startTime"))
            CancelInvoke("startTime");
        InvokeRepeating("startTime", 1, 1);

        isStarted = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 停止录音
    /// </summary>
    public void StopRecordAudio()
    {
        if (!Microphone.IsRecording(mDevice[1]))
            return;

        ShowInfoLog("Stop Recording........");
        Microphone.End(mDevice[1]);

        if (IsInvoking("startTime"))
            CancelInvoke("startTime");

        ShowInfoLog(realTime + "s");
        endtime = GetCurrentTime();

        StartCoroutine(StopAudioAndSendData());
    }

    private IEnumerator StopAudioAndSendData()
    {
        if (realTime > 5)
        {
            currentName = PrintRecordData();
            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(currentName);
            //SendMicPhoneData(content, Path.GetFileName(currentName));
            ShowInfoLog("hahaha" + content);

            CurAudioSource.mute = false;
            CurAudioSource.Play();

            yield return new WaitUntil(() => !CurAudioSource.isPlaying);

            CurAudioSource.clip = null;
        }

        isStarted = false;
        CleanTime();

        yield return null;
    }

    private void startTime()
    {
        ++realTime;
        ShowInfoLog("realTime:  " + realTime);
        if (realTime >= MaxSecond)
        {
            //若超出最大时间限制，则保存上传文件，接着上传下一次
            //ULog.Log("超出最大时间，重新监听上传");
            StopRecordAudio();
            StartRecordAudio();
        }
    }

    private void CleanTime()
    {
        realTime = 0;
    }
    public string GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  打印录音信息
    /// </summary>
    private string PrintRecordData()
    {
        if (Microphone.IsRecording(mDevice[1]))
            return null;
        byte[] data = GetClipData();
        #region 用户自由固定录音时长(此处根据实际录音时长来生成录音文件)
        int position = CurAudioSource.clip.samples / MaxSecond * realTime;
        var soundata = new float[CurAudioSource.clip.samples * CurAudioSource.clip.channels];
        CurAudioSource.clip.GetData(soundata, 0);

        var newdata = new float[position * CurAudioSource.clip.channels];
        for (int i = 0; i < newdata.Length; i++)
        {
            newdata[i] = soundata[i];
        }
        CurAudioSource.clip = AudioClip.Create(CurAudioSource.clip.name, position, CurAudioSource.clip.channels, CurAudioSource.clip.frequency, false);
        CurAudioSource.clip.SetData(newdata, 0);

        // Microphone.End(mDevice[1]);
        #endregion
        // NowTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        string fileName = filePath + "/" + "aa" + ".mp3";
        using (FileStream fs = CreateEmpty(fileName))
        {
            ConvertAndWrite(fs, CurAudioSource.clip);
            WriteHeader(fs, CurAudioSource.clip);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
    private void WriteHeader(FileStream stream, AudioClip clip)
    {
        int hz = clip.frequency;
        int channels = clip.channels;
        int samples = clip.samples;

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Byte[] riff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RIFF");
        stream.Write(riff, 0, 4);

        Byte[] chunkSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(stream.Length - 8);
        stream.Write(chunkSize, 0, 4);

        Byte[] wave = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WAVE");
        stream.Write(wave, 0, 4);

        Byte[] fmt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fmt ");
        stream.Write(fmt, 0, 4);

        Byte[] subChunk1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(16);
        stream.Write(subChunk1, 0, 4);

        UInt16 two = 2;
        UInt16 one = 1;

        Byte[] audioFormat = BitConverter.GetBytes(one);
        stream.Write(audioFormat, 0, 2);

        Byte[] numChannels = BitConverter.GetBytes(channels);
        stream.Write(numChannels, 0, 2);

        Byte[] sampleRate = BitConverter.GetBytes(hz);
        stream.Write(sampleRate, 0, 4);

        Byte[] byteRate = BitConverter.GetBytes(hz * channels * 2); // sampleRate * bytesPerSample*number of channels, here 44100*2*2  
        stream.Write(byteRate, 0, 4);

        UInt16 blockAlign = (ushort)(channels * 2);
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockAlign), 0, 2);

        UInt16 bps = 16;
        Byte[] bitsPerSample = BitConverter.GetBytes(bps);
        stream.Write(bitsPerSample, 0, 2);

        Byte[] datastring = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data");
        stream.Write(datastring, 0, 4);

        Byte[] subChunk2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(samples * channels * 2);
        stream.Write(subChunk2, 0, 4);

    }
    //创建一个空的WAV文件
    private FileStream CreateEmpty(string filepath)
    {
        ShowInfoLog(filepath);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);
        byte emptyByte = new byte();

        for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) //preparing the header  
        {
            fileStream.WriteByte(emptyByte);
        }

        return fileStream;
    }
    //AudioClip 对象转换为 WAV 格式
    private void ConvertAndWrite(FileStream fileStream, AudioClip clip)
    {

        float[] samples = new float[clip.samples];

        clip.GetData(samples, 0);

        Int16[] intData = new Int16[samples.Length];

        Byte[] bytesData = new Byte[samples.Length * 2];

        int rescaleFactor = 32767; //to convert float to Int16  

        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            intData[i] = (short)(samples[i] * rescaleFactor);
            Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[2];
            byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(intData[i]);
            byteArr.CopyTo(bytesData, i * 2);
        }
        fileStream.Write(bytesData, 0, bytesData.Length);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 获取音频数据
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The clip data.</returns>
    public byte[] GetClipData()
    {
        if (CurAudioSource.clip == null)
        {
            ShowInfoLog("缺少音频资源！");
            return null;
        }

        float[] samples = new float[CurAudioSource.clip.samples];
        CurAudioSource.clip.GetData(samples, 0);

        byte[] outData = new byte[samples.Length * 2];
        int reScaleFactor = 32767;

        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            short tempShort = (short)(samples[i] * reScaleFactor);
            byte[] tempData = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(tempShort);

            outData[i * 2] = tempData[0];
            outData[i * 2 + 1] = tempData[1];
        }
        if (outData == null || outData.Length <= 0)
        {

            ShowInfoLog("获取音频数据失败！");
            return null;
        }
        return outData;
    }

    void ShowInfoLog(string info)
    {
        Debug.Log(info);
    }
}
```

I tried to fix the logic problem in the code, however it didn't work. And I wonder how to debug the code in Visual Studio by myself.